# phpunit looks in wrong folder or fails, saying composer isn't installed

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php, vendor

I am trying to run `phpunit` through a symlink on Mac (10.10.5).

Composer is self-updated (`c85894e7920c5e83d93d88b541bc4ebf`) and phpunit is version "4.4.5".

I have the following file structure (simplified):

```
\library
  \composer
    \vendor
      \bin
        \phpunit (symlink to '../phpunit/phpunit/phpunit')
      \phpunit
        \phpunit
          \phpunit (executable)
    \composer.json
    \composer.lock
    \composer.phar
\tests
  \phpunit (symlink to '../library/composer/vendor/bin/phpunit')
  \phpunit.bootstrap.php (contains bootstrap logic)
  \phpunit.xml (see below)
```

The `phpunit.xml` file has the following contents:

```
<phpunit backupGlobals="true"
    backupStaticAttributes="false"
    bootstrap="phpunit.bootstrap.php"
    cacheTokens="false"
    colors="true"
    convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
    forceCoversAnnotation="false"
    mapTestClassNameToCoveredClassName="false"
    processIsolation="false"
    stopOnError="false"
    stopOnFailure="false"
    stopOnIncomplete="false"
    stopOnSkipped="false"
    strict="true"
    verbose="true">
</phpunit>
```

1. When I run `php tests/phpunit`, it presents me with the manual.
2. When I run `php tests/phpunit .`, it targets and runs tests in the `composer/vendor` folders.
3. When I run `php tests/phpunit unit/*` it works, but only for the contents below the `unit` folder, of course.
   How can I make `tests\phpunit` run all tests directly at and below the symlink files directory?

Answer (score 0):

Try ro remove phpunit from your composer.json file and make `composer update` and than add it to your composer.json file again and make `composer update`

I had faced with same problem using PHPUnit with Lumen and this solution fixed it.

`phpunit` command works on root folder now.